# How to fix 'errLevel 17 IBM SPSS Statistics backend is not ready' problem?

Tags: python, spss

I've tried to find a solution for my problem in the Internet but none of them have worked.

So, the problem is that when I run this code in the SPSS syntax window:

> begin program.
>
> import spss
>
> dataset = spss.ActiveDataset()
>
> print(dataset)
>
> spss.StartDataStep()
>
> sav = spss.Dataset(dataset)
>
> print(dataset.name)
>
> print(len(sav.cases))
>
> print(spss.GetVariableCount())
>
> end program.

everything works fine. While I run the first and next the second line in the IDLE window I receive this message:

> import spss
>
> dataset = spss.ActiveDataset()
>
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> >
> > File "", line 1, in
> >
> > zbior = spss.ActiveDataset()
> >
> > File "D:\Programy\SPSS\Predictive Solutions\PS IMAGO >> PRO\5\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\25\Python3\lib\site-packages\spss\spss.py", line 1936, in ActiveDataset
> >
> > raise SpssError(error)
> >
> > spss.errMsg.SpssError: [errLevel 17] IBM SPSS Statistics backend is not ready.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Note: I'm a beginner both at Python and SPSS library for Python.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's possible to run spss outside of the SPSS Syntax window?

Comment: @snakecharmerb - thanks for the answer. Did you mean 'run Python outside (...)'? If yes - it's possible. SPSS contains it's 'own' Python IDE so you can run and create Python scripts outside of the syntax window (basically it's Python 3.4.3 IDLE shell).